# Что значит "кир" в церковной иерархии? С прописной или со строчной? Склоняется ли?

Tags: церковная-лексика

В Инете - на любой вкус, а на запрос "кир" такоэ наотзывалось... плакайу.

[В субботу, 3 февраля, на другой день нашего приезда, прибыл в свои палаты **кир** Никон, патриарх московский, после того как он с августа месяца находился в отсутствии в степях и лесах из боязни чумы. Мы очень обрадовались приезду патриарха: это была первая приятная весть и радость после забот и большой тоски.](http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/rus6/Makarij/text3.phtml?id=1048)

---

[Идея составить сборник святоотеческих текстов, посвященных умному деланию и аскетическим предпосылкам к нему, принадлежала митрополиту Коринфскому св. Макарию Нотарасу (1731–1805). О мотивах, подвигших его к такому предприятию, сообщает его сподвижник и сотрудник на ниве собирания и издания святоотеческих текстов преп. Паисий Величковский, в своем письме болгарскому старцу Феодосию. Здесь он, во-первых, сообщает: «Преосвященнейший **Кир** Макарий, бывший митрополит Коринфский, еще от юного своего возраста толико неизреченную, Божиим действом, к книгам отеческим, трезвению и вниманию ума и безмолвию, и молитве умной, сиречь умом в сердце совершаемой, учащим, любовь стяжа, яко все житие свое на всеприлежнейшее взыскание оных, и трудолюбивое своею рукою, яко преискусен во внешнем учении сый, и многоиждивное руками краснописцев преписание определил есть».](https://azbyka.ru/iz-istorii-dobrotolyubiya#f1)

---

[Обрати внимание на удивительный порядок, с каким записывал упомянутый секретарь так: "Лета 7163 от сотворения мира, в воскресенье, 11 февраля, **кир** Макарий, святейший из людей своего времени, патриарх Антиохии и всего Востока, прибыл к его величеству, высочайшему царю и самодержцу. В подарки, кои он привез с собою от своего святого престола, и святыни из его священной страны".](http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/rus6/Makarij/text3.phtml?id=1048)

---

[У нас настала великая радость, благодаря многочисленным приятным известиям, кои сообщали нам драгоманы, о любви царя к нашему учителю, которая оправдалась на деле, ибо обыкновенно, по приезде патриархов в Москву, они имеют свидание с царем только спустя две недели времени, что было с **кир** Паисием иерусалимским и **кир** Афанасием Пателярием, низложенным (патриархом) константинопольским, наш же учитель (был принят) на третий день.](http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/rus6/Makarij/text3.phtml?id=1048)

---

[Потом, по его приказанию, певчие пропели многолетие патриарху московскому **кир** Никону и царь, сначала выпив его здравицу, также раздавал вино всем присутствующим.](http://www.vostlit.info/Texts/rus6/Makarij/text3.phtml?id=1048)

---

[Отец же его, преосвященнейший митрополит **кир** Филарет, давно был отправлен в Польшу святейшим патриархом **кир** Гермогеном и собором к великому королю Сигизмунду вместе с великим боярином князем Василием Голицыным и со многими боярами и дьяками великого двора, с архимандритами, игуменами, иереями, иеродиаконами и купцами и со многими дарами, в бытность тогда великого короля под Смоленском, большим городом, при его осаде.](https://www.sedmitza.ru/lib/text/439062/)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Кир*** (господин, великий господин) - почетное наименование  архиереев и патриархов.

1) «ВЕЛИКИЙ ГОСПОДИН»

В наст. время почетное именование Святейшего Патриарха Московского и всея Руси при возношении его имени за богослужением: «Еще молимся о **Великом Господине** и отце нашем Святейшем Патриархе Алексии...»

В РПЦ употребляется также за богослужением при возношении имен Предстоятелей автокефальных правосл. Церквей **в сане Патриарха**.

В **грекоязычных Церквах** аналогичное значение имеет удвоенное титулование «Кир Кир» (греч. Κύριος Κύριος букв.- Господин Господин). **Слово «Кир», но без удвоения, употреблялось по отношению к архиереям**, в т. ч. и к Патриархам и в РПЦ **в досинодальную эпоху**.

Так, **в 1675 г.** Освященный Собор установил офиц. звание Патриарха Иоакима (Савёлова) в форме: **«Великий Господин Святейший Кир Иоаким, Милостию Божией Патриарх Московский и всея Руси».** В первый период Патриаршества почетное обращение «В. Г.» употреблялось по отношению к Патриарху не только за богослужением, **но и в офиц. деловой переписке, и при личном общении.** Патриархи той эпохи Филарет (Романов) и Никон (Минов) титуловались «Великими Государями» одинаково с царями.

http://www.pravenc.ru/text/150099.html

Написание ***Кир, Великий Господин*** с прописной буквы (как и все особо важные титулы и слова в церковных текстах).

2) Слово ***кир*** в приведенном тексте не склоняется и пишется со строчной буквы:

XVI,7

А так как **с деспотом кир Константином** связывала меня дружба и полное доверие, которым благоволил бог (ведь брат моего отца был его воспитателем, а его сыновья и я вместе с ними -товарищами, друзьями и слугами его, затем пришло время и меня сделали приближенным его покойного незабвенного отца, и то многое и необходимое, в чем он нуждался, получал через меня), то он особенно хотел, чтобы я был у него на службе.

http://myriobiblion.byzantion.ru/sphrantzi.htm

Answer (score 1):

кир (от др.-греч. κύριος, «господин») — дополнительный титул, использовавшийся (и использующийся) в именовании архиереев и патриархов православных (и греко-католических) церквей.

Кир — [греч. κῦρ; от κύριος - господин, владыка], часть титулования вост. духовенства, в т. ч. патриархов. На рус. язык не переводится и не склоняется, напр.: «О еже не впасти в ересь Варлаама и Акиндина, кир Давида мниха и философа изложение» (см. ст. Давид Дисипат). В досинодальный период РПЦ слово «кир» входило в титул рус. архиереев и патриархов, напр.: «Святейший Кир Иоаким, Милостию Божией Патриарх Московский и всея Руси» (звание, установленное на Освященном Соборе 1675 г. ). Иногда используется с удвоением: Κῦρ Κῦρ, что соответствует почетному наименованию патриарха «Великий Господин».

В Византийской империи "кир" в качестве почетного наименования относилось также к императорам. Такое употребление этого слова зафиксировано уже у византийского писателя и историка Михаила Пселла (XI век).

Церковные титулы — со строчной буквы (даже патриарх).

Но "Кир" также может быть мужским именем.

Кир — мужское имя греческого или персидского происхождения.